# Setting up Passwordless login in quiet mode

Tags: ssh, login

Problem: For running the testcases for my utility, prerequisite is to setup a passwordless login to the linux localhost :

Commands that I executed in sequence:

```
1. touch  ~/.ssh/known_hosts
2. ssh-keygen -R <host>
3. ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f "<home>/.ssh/id_rsa"
4. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ; chmod 700 ~/.ssh ; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <host>
```

This returns an error "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key"
and asks me to enter the password for the user.

What can I do to eliminate the user interaction completely?

Answer (score 0):

I got it Now I am able to login passwordless.
Commands required are:

```
1. ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
2. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ; chmod 700 ~/.ssh ; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. ssh-add
```